# jnius.jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: setAudioSource failed

Tags: python, android, audio, microphone, pyjnius

As `PyAudio` is not compatible with android, tried using the following code with `jnius` in python:

```
    if platform == 'android':
        from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission

        request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                             Permission.INTERNET, Permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                             Permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT])

        # get the needed Java classes
        self.MediaRecorder = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder')
        self.AudioSource = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder$AudioSource')
        self.OutputFormat = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder$OutputFormat')
        self.AudioEncoder = autoclass('android.media.MediaRecorder$AudioEncoder')
        #String = autoclass("java.lang.String")

        # create out recorder
        self.mRecorder = self.MediaRecorder()
        self.mRecorder.setAudioSource(self.AudioSource.MIC)
        self.mRecorder.setOutputFormat(self.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
        self.mRecorder.setOutputFile('/sdcard/test_recording.mp4')
        self.mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(self.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)
        self.mRecorder.prepare()
```

However exception appear as the app tries to load

`jnius.jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: setAudioSource failed`

And the application crashes.
As can be seen in the code, I tried giving all permissions. As the application loads, it does ask for the media permission, while it doesn't ask for Microphone permission.

I checked the settings for microphone and surprisingly my application is not even listed there to be enabled (Probably because the installation source is not Playstore).

How can I overcome this issue? Any help is appreciated.

Further on, the root cause of the issue is permission denied for Record Audio. This is happening while I am requesting for the RECORD_AUDIO permissions.

01-07 14:08:41.497  1417  1834 D CompatibilityInfo: applicationScale - 1.0
01-07 14:08:41.499  2331  2693 I ProcessMonitor: onForegroundInfoChanged: ForegroundInfo{mForegroundPackageName='com.google.android.packageinstaller', mForegroundUid=10023, mForegroundPid=2558, mLastForegroundPackageName='jigyasu.net.voiceasstmob', mLastForegroundUid=10197, mLastForegroundPid=4691, mMultiWindowForegroundPackageName='null', mMultiWindowForegroundUid=-1, mFlags=0}
01-07 14:08:41.499  2331  2693 I GameBoosterService: onForegroundInfoChanged: Cur=com.google.android.packageinstaller    last=jigyasu.net.voiceasstmob
01-07 14:08:41.499   794 18980 W ServiceManager: Permission failure: android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO from uid=10197 pid=4691
01-07 14:08:41.500   794 18980 E MediaRecorderService: Request requires android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
01-07 14:08:41.500  2331  2693 D GameBoosterService: onGameStatusChange foreground:ForegroundInfo{mForegroundPackageName='com.google.android.packageinstaller', mForegroundUid=10023, mForegroundPid=2558, mLastForegroundPackageName='jigyasu.net.voiceasstmob', mLastForegroundUid=10197, mLastForegroundPid=4691, mMultiWindowForegroundPackageName='null', mMultiWindowForegroundUid=-1, mFlags=0}
01-07 14:08:41.500  2331  2693 I GameBoosterService: onForegroundInfoChanged: Exit
01-07 14:08:41.500  2331  2693 I VideoBoxUtils: isSupportVideoBox: false
01-07 14:08:41.501  2331  2693 I VideoToolBoxService: onForegroundInfoChanged: Exit Vtb
01-07 14:08:41.503  4691  4714 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):

Interestingly, I do not find my app listed under microphone permissions of the phone, meaning I am not able to grant permission manually also.
Is there some fundamental problem with the app?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer if anybody faces the same in future:
in your spec file mention permission for RECORD_AUDIO. While Storage permission can be asked through code, the MICROPHONE permission has to be mentioned in the spec file